# Google Sheets Update Filter data range when new rows aded

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet with several tabs. Data is written to the 'tracker' tab constantly by a script which is writing information from incoming files. So new rows are constantly being added.

The tracker tab has a number of 'filter views' built using the UI. The data range that these filter views point to does not update when new rows are added.

I have seen some scripts which seem to be able to update the range if usng the Google Sheets API. However, I need something that runs within Google Apps Script itself..

Can anyone help?

Comment: Sheets API can be used with Google Apps Script. But, from `I have seen some scripts which seem to be able to update the range if usng the Google Sheets API. However, I need something that runs within Google Apps Script itself..`, you want to achieve your goal without using Sheets API. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes. I work within 'the business' as opposed to within IT in this company so I do not have access to any other tools, only the Google suite..

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, you cannot use Sheets API at Advanced Google services. And, you cannot propose to permit to use of Sheets API for the administrator of Google workspace. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike Hi, I googled "Advanced Google Services" to then realise I can add Google Sheets API via the services tab, so thanks for responding. This should set me on the right path now.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If in your situation, you can use Sheets API at Advanced Google services and your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to add the Google Sheets API via the add Services menu.